# Blazorise chart with timeseries data

Tags: charts, blazor, blazorise

I am developing a portal with Blazor. The website will show some timeseries data in a chart.
For the charts I use Blazorise.Charts (1.0.5).

I want the chart to show the full date at the start of a day and between the days only hours (in a 24h format) and minutes. However it seems the Blazorise LineChartOptions do not accept my input.

My data model:

```cs
public class point
{
    public double Value;
    public DateTime ReceivedOn;
}
```

The options I use

```cs
public LineChartOptions _LineChartOptions { get; set; } = new LineChartOptions()
{
    Parsing = new ChartParsing
    {
        XAxisKey = "ReceivedOn",
        YAxisKey = "Value",
    },
    Scales = new ChartScales()
    {
        X = new ChartAxis()
        {
            Display = true,
            Type = "timeseries",
            Title = new ChartScaleTitle
            {
                Display = true,
                Text = "Date"
            },
            Ticks = new ChartAxisTicks
            {
                StepSize = 1,
                Major = new ChartAxisMajorTick
                {
                    Enabled = true
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the `Time = new ChartAxisTime`, but that option does not seem to work if you use Ticks.

The result I get when using these settings is:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzgoj.png)

Like you can see, it seems almost what I want, however the labels need to be in the HH:mm format and the date needs to be in the yyyy-MM-dd format.

What do I need to change to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Honestly, after reading the Chart.js documentation, I just stopped trying to feed `DateTime` objects directly into the blazorise chart. According to the Chart.js documentation, it must be converted somewhere in blazorise, because the dates are fed into Chart.js as strings anyway. So I converted my `DateTime[]` to a `string[]` with `DateTime` pattern `"O"` (o Format Specifier de-DE Culture 2008-10-31T17:04:32.0000000) and everything went fine.

Furthermore, try `time` first instead of `timeseries` as the x scale type. Type `timeseries` behaves strangely on non-equidistant data.

My `LineChartOptions`:

```
public static LineChartOptions CreateLineChartOptions()
    {
        return new LineChartOptions()
        {
            Scales = new ChartScales()
            {
                X = new ChartAxis()
                {
                    Type = "time",
                    Time = new ChartAxisTime()
                    {
                        Unit = "minute",
                        MinUnit = "minute"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

My labels are wrongly formatted like yours; I'm still working on that.

My Razor Call:

```
<LineChart @ref="lineChart" TItem="double" Options="@LineChartOptions" />
```

For a minimum example, you can even leave the `ChartAxisTime()` object. It should run without it.

My minimal result:

[image]